# Compilation Error in building a multi-project solution with Teamcity

Tags: git, visual-studio, teamcity

I'm trying two build a Visual Studio(2013) solution in TeamCity. The solution contains three projects, one web project and two class library projects. I'm using Git for VCS and here is what the VCS root looks like:

[image: VCS root]

When I try to run a build, TeamCity shows the following error:

[image: TeamCity error]

I'm using Visual Studio(sln) runner type in my build step. And also the project builds without errors locally in Visual Studio.

What is the causing the error? How can I solve it?

Disclaimer: I'm new to both build automation and TeamCity.

Comment: Have a look in the Build Log in TeamCity for that build configuration to see more details on execution, the answer may be there. Another option is to login to Teamcity server and execute the same command it is running to see the sequence firsthand. That could give an insight what's happening and what's wrong there.

Comment: @avidProgrammer : Open the project in the checkoutdirectory in Visual Studio 2013 and try to rebuild it. This will show you a clear idea of what is wrong

Comment: @Rod, Oddly enough, the build log doesn't show anything.

Comment: @NevinRajVictor, I did what you suggested and still the error shows up.

Comment: @avidProgrammer : I am pretty sure that visual studio will give you the exact error message and not just compilation error.Check that

Comment: @NevinRajVictor, okay, may be I didn't understand when you said "Open the project in the checkoutdirectory". What do you mean by the checkoutdirectory?

Comment: @avidProgrammer : When you run the build in teamcity,the code will checked out to a folder.By default it will be at Teamcity/buildagent/work/ .Open the checkedout code there in visual studio and try and build.

Comment: @NevinRajVictor, you are right! After opening the project in the checkout directory in the VS, there are some frameworks not recognized and the build fails because of that. How do I make TeamCity download those frameworks for a successful build?

Comment: @avidProgrammer :I think it's because of missing packages. Use a Nuget Installer build step to restore your packages. If it's not that, make sure you have pushed the code to repository properly.May be you are not pushing the entire code to the repository which causes missing frameworks

Comment: @NevinRajVictor, Yeah, I solved the problem. Thank you for your suggestions. Add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @avidProgrammer : Most welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the build in teamcity,the code will checked out to a folder.By default it will be at ***Teamcity/buildagent/work/*** .

Open the checkedout code there in visual studio and try and build.I am pretty sure that visual studio will give you the exact error message of what's going wrong.

Missing frameworks may be because of missing packages. Use a **Nuget Installer** build step to restore your packages. If it's not that, make sure you have pushed the code to repository properly.May be you are not pushing the entire code to the repository which causes missing frameworks.

Comment: However, TeamCity is not showing me any build logs. When I open the build log tab, it shows nothing. How can I solve that? The TeamCity I'm using is v9.1.3(if that helps).

Comment: @avidProgrammer : Teamcity will definitely give you the same build log if you are using the Visual Studio(sln) runner type in  build step. May be you are looking it wrong.